# querySelectorAll and selecting specific children

Tags: javascript, css

Assume I have the HTML below

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <p>Test1</p>
  <p>Test5</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>Test3</p>
  <p>Test7</p>
</div>
```

I want to select the 2nd child in each `.container` via vanilla javascript (Test5 and Test 7).

How would I do that?

If I do this

```
var container = document.querySelectorAll(".container p");
console.log(container[1]);
```

It only returns Test5 rather than the second child in both containers

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Adding `:nth-child(2)` (or `:last-child` in your example) will do it. These are the same selectors that CSS uses, so if you're familiar with those, then you'll have an idea of what can be done.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll(".container p");` gives you a list of four DOM elements. `container[1]` and `container[3]` would be the elements you want, but that's not a reliable solution.

Comment: thank you everyone

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `:nth-child` selector:

```js
var secondChilds = document.querySelectorAll(".container p:nth-child(2)");
console.log(secondChilds);
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Test1</p>
  <p>Test5</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>Test3</p>
  <p>Test7</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using ES6. Maybe a lil' bit overcomplicated - but works fine.

```js
let elems = document.getElementsByClassName('container');
Array.from(elems).forEach(function(v){
  v.children[1].style.color = 'blue';
})
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Test1</p>
  <p>Test5</p>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <p>Test3</p>
  <p>Test7</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't need ES6 for that. You may simply do `[].forEach.call(elems, function(v){...` or just use a simple `for` loop.

Comment: @DenysSéguret I just prefer ES6 (: